# How can i find shortest point on a polygon from a point to that polygon (not it's distance )

Tags: java, javascript, polygon, point, shortest

I have a point that may be inside or outside of a polygon,i need to find the shortest point on the polygon from the point.

thanx in advance

Comment: What's your progress so far? Please show some code.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your post to contain your attempts at solving the problem so far, as well as results and errors you received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this answers your question, but here's a piece of code I wrote several years ago.
It calculates the point index out of a list of polygon points and the distance of the perpendicular to the nearest edge.

It uses a `Vector2` struct that defines the vector operators `+`, `-`, `*` (dot product) and methods `GetLength` and `GetSquaredLength`.  The same code should run with a `Vector3` (3D) also.

Please see comments for details.

```
    // Polygon points
    List<Vector2> p;

    /// <summary> Calculates the perpendicular vector from nearest point on polygon to given point. If no points available minIndex is -1. </summary>
    public void GetPolygonDist(Vector2 point, out Vector2 minDist, out int minIndex) {
        if (p.Count == 0) { minDist = Vector2.Null(); minIndex = -1; return; }
        Vector2 dist;
        minDist = point - p[0];
        minIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < p.Count - 1; i++) {
            Vector2 l = p[i + 1] - p[i];                                        // Edge
            if (l.GetLength() < 1e-9) continue;                                 // Ignore edge of length almost zero
            Vector2 d = point - p[i];                                           // Polygon point to point
            Vector2 b = (l * d) / (l * l) * l;                                  // Projection to edge
            double f = Math.Sign(b * l) * (b.GetLength() / l.GetLength());      // Where on the edge is the perpendicular?
            if (f < 0.0) dist = point - p[i];                                   // Point before the edge
            else if (f > 1.0) dist = point - p[i + 1];                          // Point after the edge
            else dist = d - b;                                                  // Perpendicular
            if (dist.GetSquaredLength() < minDist.GetSquaredLength()) {
                minDist = dist;
                minIndex = i;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanx ,but i need a js

Comment: You didn't tag it js. Its a bit math, so transform this into js should not be very hard.